# Trying to access array offset on value of type null on CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

When i tried to acces **comic/create**
it shows me the error message

but in the detail it show another page that have error

> **APPPATH\Views\comic\detail.php at line 10**

and on line 10 it have this

```
<img src="/img/<?= $comic['cover']; ?>" class="card-img">
```

Can you explain how to fix this, because I was following tutorial on this project. But it gives me these errors. Meanwhile on the tutorial it runs with no problem.

Comment: As the error says, your `$comic` is null therefore it cannot access the 'cover' value. If you want more help you will have to be more specific

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already fix it. it because i havent create routes to my comic/create